# Apple Watch Storyboards

Tags: storyboard, watchkit, apple-watch

I recently got invited to Apple's  Watch Lab and I'm really excited. The thing is, I don't know how to start. I have the iOS portion complete, but the Storyboards are confusing me.

1. I don't know how to put a background image view for the storyboard on the Watch.
2. I cannot put a label on top of the image view for the background of the Watch. I cannot even place buttons over it.
3. Where do we write the code for the Watch? When I add a new target, I just get a storyboard, nothing else.

My application is written in Objective C and I'm planning to switch it over to Swift.  If anyone could answer these questions, that'd be great! Thank you!

[image: As you can see, in the storyboard, all these buttons and labels are separated, not together like they'd be on the storyboard for iOS. By together I mean I can move it freely.]

Comment: If you add an app via the "New Target" menu, you should get both an "App" folder and an "Extension" folder.  The extension technically runs on the iPhone, that is where the code goes.  The "App" contains the interface and image files.

Comment: And I'm not sure that Watch storyboards support layered controls.

Answer (score 0):

The apple watch UI is made of groups. To get an image the full size of the screen, create a group that comprises of the whole screen and than add an image view to the group.

I do not think that WatchKit supports layering, so you can't put a label ***on*** the image, but you can put an label ***under*** the image.

You write the code for WatchKit in a view controller, akin to iOS. Xcode has the ability to create these files for you when you create the watch target.

Comment: Hmm, still doesn't let me center the text or free move my labels around the Interface Controller.

Answer (score 0):

To place a label over an image:

Create a full screen group and set the image as its background.

Add a Label to the group.

Basics:

> WatchKit apps do not use the same layout model as iOS apps. When
>   assembling the scenes of your WatchKit app interface, you do not
>   create view hierarchies by placing elements arbitrarily in the
>   available space. Instead, as you add elements to your scene, Xcode
>   positions the items for you, stacking them vertically on different
>   lines.
>
> The size and position of most items can be configured using the
>   Attributes inspector. Group objects offer another important tool for
>   positioning items, allowing you to lay out elements horizontally as
>   well as vertically. Groups also offer extra options for spacing items
>   within the group bounds. Groups have no default visual representation
>   but can be configured with a background color or image if you want.

Answer (score 0):

To start coding, just simply press the button at the top right which looks like two rings overlapping each other. From there you can choose which file (.h or .m file for example) you want to be displayed.

EDIT: For the background, you click on the screen in the storyboard so it's highlighted blue. Then you click on the fourth tab in the pane to the right. There you'll see "background, mode, animate, color" etc. The background is probably set to "no image", which you then can change by choosing one that you've imported to your project.

Good luck!